# PHP db connection variable, best way to access in multiple places

Tags: php

Okay, it seems the word on the street is that global variables are bad.

Well, if I have:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```

and then I have several functions and such that all depend on that db connection, what is the most sound way to access $dbc in all my functions?

Is this a case where making it global is okay? Declaring it as a global variable inside each function seems redundant.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the global variables won't be a problem.

Another way to tackle this though could be to write a Database class which stores these variables. The plus side of this is that if you feel you need to switch to a new database handler, say PDO, it will be a rather simple task.

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->host = '';
        $this->dbname = '';
        $this->user = '';
        $this->password = '';
    }

    public function connect()   {
        return mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->dbname);
    }
}
?>
```

In the future you could easily:

- switch to PDO without worrying about massive refactoring
- you could inject connection details into the constructor
- use the Singleton pattern to store your connection

Comment: Thanks much. Just beginning to tackle classes and objects so I appreciate this example.